# Execute antivirus program programmatically using delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, antivirus-integration, windows-xp-sp2

I wrote an small app to transfer files using the indy components, now i want start the antivirus program when the transfer is finished to check the files.

how i can execute the antivirus program installed in the client side, when the download finish?

**UPDATE**
I need implement something similar to firefox when download a file and then execute the antivirus installed in the machine.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't most antivirus programs hook into the file system and detect new files anyway?

Comment: Are you asking how to make an application start automatically on the other user's computer (not yours)?  Are you trying to make a service?  You wrote an anti-virus program or you want to make the anti-virus program scan your program which is not an anti-virus program? I am confused.

Comment: @Warren P, i updated my question. just i need scan a file using the installed antivirus when my client app finished the download.

Comment: Don't do it. Let the antivirus engine and the OS handle it. Stick to one thing for your application and let the other applications do their thing.

Comment: I have asked this in a more general way over here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295478/how-does-firefox-version-3-invoke-the-anti-virus-feature-on-windows-to-scan-a-dow

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[See the nice person's answer to my other question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295478/how-does-firefox-version-3-invoke-the-anti-virus-feature-on-windows-to-scan-a-dow)

Looks like there are two COM interfaces you should be grabbing, one of which is documented here:

[IAttachmentExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776297%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

This interface is part of the windows shell interfaces.

here is the commentary in the source

```
/**
 * Code overview
 *
 * Download scanner attempts to make use of one of two different virus
 * scanning interfaces available on Windows - IOfficeAntiVirus (Windows
 * 95/NT 4 and IE 5) and IAttachmentExecute (XPSP2 and up).  The latter
 * interface supports calling IOfficeAntiVirus internally, while also
 * adding support for XPSP2+ ADS forks which define security related
 * prompting on downloaded content.  
 *
 * Both interfaces are synchronous and can take a while, so it is not a
 * good idea to call either from the main thread. Some antivirus scanners can
 * take a long time to scan or the call might block while the scanner shows
 * its UI so if the user were to download many files that finished around the
 * same time, they would have to wait a while if the scanning were done on
 * exactly one other thread. Since the overhead of creating a thread is
 * relatively small compared to the time it takes to download a file and scan
 * it, a new thread is spawned for each download that is to be scanned. Since
 * most of the mozilla codebase is not threadsafe, all the information needed
 * for the scanner is gathered in the main thread in nsDownloadScanner::Scan::Start.
 * The only function of nsDownloadScanner::Scan which is invoked on another
 * thread is DoScan.
```

[I found some more implementation information here. The feature is called AES.](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2005/08/19/3485.aspx)

Comment: The C++ source showing how Firefox does it is at http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla1.9.1/source/toolkit/components/downloads/src/nsDownloadScanner.cpp

Answer (score 2):

Check how other programs do it, like Winrar. Most likely it is just starting the anti-virus program with the file or folder you want to scan as a command-line parameter. You can check the manual of your anti-virus program to check how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

you can use shellexecute or createprocess,
  i use shellexecute but i've heard createprocess is better
 if you want to execute an antivirus called say antivvv using shellapi do it this way:

```
uses ShellApi;
 ...
 ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', 'c:\program files\antivvv.exe', nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL) ;
```

Comment: I'm not the one, but probably because it doesn't do anything to make the AV to check a file.

Comment: That only depends on the command line options of the antivirus program. -1 seems harsh.

Comment: I think this question is just about unanswerable. It leaves too much out.  Mason's answer is one possible understanding of a very confusing and full-of-holes question.