# How to ask VB to virus-check a specific file

Tags: winapi, vb6, antivirus, antivirus-integration

Is there an API call which will request the anti-virus software to check a specific file (same as right-clicking a file in Explorer and choosing Scan)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3295709 might help. It describes the COM interfaces that are available to do so.

Comment: There is nothing in VB6 for this, so any answer will be generic for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You should look for a command-line interface. If such a interface exists, you can run it with a special command-line using [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx).